# Uncaught ReferenceError $ionicHistory is not defined

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I was trying to prevent native back Button default behavior in my ionic app(android platform) and after close to 1 day of googling i came across this solution

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === 'tab.home.share'){
event.preventDefault();
} else {
$ionicHistory.goBack();
}
}, 100);
```

it disables  the native back button default behavior but $ionicHistory.goBack() doesnt work and i get the error Uncaught Reference $ionicHistory is not defined.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add $ionicHistory dependency in your controller...

Comment: Did you inject $ionicHistory in your run function or controller?

Comment: Thanks for the response all, i had to inject $ionicHistory into run function as @JanP said and it worked lke a charm :)

Comment: Please agree to the answer so that it will help others